# Flutter IOS getInitialMessage not redirecting

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am running FCM transactions in my Flutter application. All of these processes run on android. In iOS, messages are received and forwarded while the application is in the background or running. However, if the application is closed on my iOS device, clicking on the notification does not perform the expected redirection. here are my codes:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2)).then((value) {
      setupInitialMessage();
    });
  }

  Future<void> setupInitialMessage() async {
    RemoteMessage? remoteMessage =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

    if (remoteMessage != null) {
      AppRouting.notificationPushRouting(remoteMessage.data);
    }
  }
```

AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
  override func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
  application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
}
```